# Symfony2 ManyToMany in one query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have 2 entities related ManyToMany

```
class Product
{

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductTransfer", inversedBy="product")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_transfers")
 */
private $transfers;
```

and second one

```
class ProductTransfer
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="stock_from_id", type="integer")
 */
private $stockFromId;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="stock_to_id", type="integer")
 */
private $stockToId;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
 */
private $productId;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product",mappedBy="transfers")
 */
private $product;
```

All works great, additional table were created by Doctrine.
But when I'm trying to get all rows from `ProductTransfers` I see in profiler that each row need one single query with 2 joins.
So for 5000 products it will be really many queries.

Is there any way to get them all in one query like in "clean SQL"?
If there is no way to do it with Doctrine, what is best way to achieve that?

Like:

```
SELECT * FROM product_transfer pt
LEFT JOIN products_transfers pts ON pt.product_id=pts.product_id
LEFT JOIN product p ON pts.product_id=p.id;
```

edit:
created method in repository

```
public function loadTransfersByStock($stockId)
{

    $q = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT pt,p FROM AppBundle:ProductTransfer pt
            LEFT JOIN AppBundle:Product p WITH pt.productId=p.id
            WHERE pt.stockToId = :stockId'
        );

    return $q->setParameter('stockId', $stockId)->getResult();
}
```

and then result is

```
ProductsController.php on line 495:
array:3 [▼
  0 => ProductTransfer {#1071 ▶}
  1 => Product {#1084 ▶}
  2 => ProductTransfer {#1099 ▶}
]
```

Comment: Yes just join in the relations you need, show you query, unclear if you're using a query builder or dql

Comment: @JimL I'm using entityManager and repository to get them, so I should use custom SQL query?

Comment: You should make your own method in the repository and use the query builder or dql, whichever you prefer

Comment: @JimL I added to my question method which I create in repo, but still the same...

Comment: use relations in query builder / dql. `join pt.product`, it seems to depend on using the named relations (from the entities) to do this correctly. btw in a many to many relation it would make sense if that releation was also plural (it is from the other side)

Comment: @JimL I just made it, few seconds after reading Your comment, now all working as expected, thanks so much

Comment: Great! You just got a lot more powerful using doctrine :) I suggest you look into fetching partial objects as fetching large quantities of entities may be resource intensive. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#partial-object-syntax

Answer (score 0):

By default Doctrine uses lazy loading in object relations - the rows for the relationships are only loaded when you try to access them. If you know you're going to be needing all the related rows, try changing to eager fetching.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductTransfer", inversedBy="product", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="products_transfers")
 */
```

Comment: @Kaivisukeltaja added, without any result

Comment: @rafwlaz, it needs to be added to the entity that you're using as the entry point - try adding it to the other one?

Comment: @Kaivisukeltaja I fix it as wrote in comment to my question, now all works correct

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing the query like that in the repository, you are skipping the way doctrine "wants" you to write it. So instead of that, I would do something like this:

```
//ProductTransferRepository.php
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('pt');
$qb
    ->select('pt, p') // here you can choose the columns you want if you don't need everything from both tables
    ->leftJoin('pt.product', 'p')
    ->where('pt.stockToId = :stockId')
    ->setParameter('stockId', $stockId)
;
return $qb
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()
;
```

Use `getArrayResult` to fetch results as array rather than objects, especially because you have many queries.